# Implementation of KNN in R

Tags: performance, matrix, r, clustering, data-mining

I have implemented the K-Nearest Neighbor algorithm with Euclidean distance in R. It works fine but takes tremendously huge time than the library function (get.knn). Please point out the possibility of improvement.

```
knn<-function(list,k){
  n=nrow(list)
  if (n<=k) stop("k can not be more than n-1")
  neigh<- matrix(0,nrow=n,ncol=k)
  for(i in 1:n){
    dist<-matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=n)
    for (j in 1:n){
      dist[j,1]<-j
      dist[j,2]<-sum((list[i,]-list[j,])^2)
      #dist[j,2]<-dtw(list[i,],list[j,])$distance
    }
    sorted<-dist[order(dist[,2]),]
    neigh[i,]<-sorted[2:(k+1),1]
  }
  return(neigh)
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify a couple things: is `list` a matrix and what are its typical dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve your code by using vectorization to speed up the computation of Euclidean distances in the inner loop. The code would be:

```
knn <- function(mat, k){
   n <- nrow(mat)
   if (n <= k) stop("k can not be more than n-1")
   neigh <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = k)
   for(i in 1:n) {
      euc.dist <- colSums((mat[i, ] - t(mat)) ^ 2)  
      neigh[i, ] <- order(euc.dist)[2:(k + 1)]
   }
   return(neigh)
}
```

Notice that I also made a few changes:

- `list` is a function in R so calling your object `list` is a pretty bad idea. Also, in the R language, a "list" refers to a very specific data structure, while your code seems to be using a matrix. So calling that input `mat` seemed more appropriate.
- Similarly, there is a `dist` function in R so it is a bad idea to name your variable this way. I chose `euc.dist` since you were computing an euclidean distance.
- `order` already returns an index, so the whole idea of column-biding your indices and distances was not necessary: you just need a vector of distances.

The code above might still be a bit too slow because of the computations inside the `for` loop. If the dimensions of your matrix are not astronomical, you could compute the matrix of distances at first using a compiled function. I once tested about a dozen of packages and found that `fields::rdist` (written in Fortran) was the fastest. If you do not wish to install it, you can use the `base::dist` function. The code would look like this:

```
knn <- function(mat, k){
   n <- nrow(mat)
   if (n <= k) stop("k can not be more than n-1")
   neigh <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = k)
   library(fields)
   dist.mat <- rdist(mat, mat)
   for(i in 1:n) {
      euc.dist <- dist.mat[i, ]
      neigh[i, ] <- order(euc.dist)[2:(k + 1)]
   }
   return(neigh)
}
```

If my first suggestion is still too slow and your matrix is so large that my second solution cannot be used, you might want to use a mix between the two approaches, where you loop on chunks of rows, i.e. rely on `rdist(chunk_of_rows_from_mat, mat)`. But I'll leave that to you as an exercise :-)

Finally, I will point out that if you are interested, you could search CRAN or the internet for a package that does exactly what you are after. KNN is a  very common tool and there must be packages (compiled from C) that already do it much faster than this code will do. But not much to be learnt there...

Comment: The first code works better but still not fast enough. I want to get the neighbors based on DTW distance. There is no library available for the same. I think writing the code in python might work faster.

Comment: I tried to add `resultat <- knn(i,3)` but how to understand the output as far as I get lines such as `[1,]    2    3    4` or `[5,]    4    5    1` I know it sorts and returns the positions but how can I get the actual flowers ? and the line's expected classes ?